# Fingerprint sensor working only for login

Tags: dell, fingerprint-reader

On my Dell laptop, after adding the Dell software sources, the fingerprint sensor started working properly. Now I upgraded to 21.04 and the fingerprint sensor is only working to login (GDM), but not when using `sudo` in terminal or when the GUI popup asks you to authenticate.

I'm suspecting that the upgrade process must have undone something that the installation had done.

How do I re-enable the fingerprint sensor for these other situations when authentication is required?

Answer (score 0):

I had what looks like the same problem after upgrading.  I fixed it by adapting the advice from https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fprint#Login_configuration for Ubuntu.

In a terminal run `sudoedit /etc/pam.d/common-auth`, and add the line:

```
auth    sufficient                      pam_fprintd.so
```

immediately before the existing line:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the command mentioned by Martin in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1337267/27968), I read in the comments in the file that it is managed by pam-auth-update.

So instead of making manual changes to such sensitive files, I exited without making changes and ran `sudo pam-auth-update` I enabled the fingerprint sensor and saved.

Now I'm being asked to authenticate with the fingerprint sensor on running `sudo` commands.